# String formatting for mailing

Tags: php, string

Here's the issue.

I make a sring with php like this

```
$string ="text";
$string .="text";
$string .="text".$AVarOverHere."more text";
$string .="text";
$string .="text";

echo $AVarOverHere;
```

This is all working good.
But I want to send it as email
with Mail.php class that use Pear

So I use

```
$mail_object->send($recipients, $headers, $string);
```

Here is the problem.

It's not working when I send the text with the $AvarOverHere that is coming from a function that generate a random string

The function:

```
function genRandomString() { 
    $length = 6;
    $characters = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
$string ="";    
    for ($p = 0; $p < $length; $p++) {
        $string .= $characters[mt_rand(0, (strlen($characters))-1)];
    }
    return $string;
}
```

But the funny thing is that if I just do:

```
$AVarOverHere = 'some string';
```

It's working!?
 So what the heck!
Anyone know what to do?

Answer (score 1):

Just for kicks, change the `"`s to `'`s. Sometimes that fixes things...

Comment: Not that. i really dont get it. if i echo it work if i mail i it doesnt!

Comment: Ok...are you echoing out the random string? Instead of "return $string" within the genRandomString function, echo it. See what happens.